# ABAC with Spring SPEL - check if a project is assigned to a user through a from a list of projects

Tags: spring-boot, access-control, spring-el, abac

I'm new to `spEL`. Im trying to implement attribute based access control in a `spring boot` application using `spEL`.

I pass the user object and the project to the access control provider to evaluate permission.

Below is my policy file to check permission for access control

```
"target": "subject.role.name() == 'PM' && action == 'PROJECTS_VIEW'",
"condition": "{subject.projects}.contains == resource"
```

in this the resource is an object of type project, and in the data model a user has many projects assigned to him.

I want to check if this particular project belongs to the users project list.

Will this evaluation work for the requirement?

I checked many resources, but failed to find a good example of implementing ABAC using `spEL` in a spring application.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered ALFA or XACML rather than SpEL?

Comment: No, is there any advantage of using XACML over spEL? In the case of spEL, I have to pass the object so that the data is retrievable from the object as "X.property.id". Therefore, I have to write separate methods for separate access control options based on the object I'm passing and it seems like poor implementation.

Comment: Spel has little support afaik. XACML, ALFA, or REGO are the way to go

Comment: Thanks David, I will have a look at XACML.